# Why does the player in my pygame game not move?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having an issue where I'm trying to get player controls set up, however when I run the game, the "image" stays the same, so the player doesn't move.
The thing with this is that I've added print functions to see where it doesn't work, but it looks like there should be no issues, so I have no idea why it doesn't work.

DISCLAIMER: I have to make use of classes

See the code under for reference in player class:

```py
def update(self):
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.right < self.screen_rect.right:
            self.player_x += self.player_speed
            print("player has moved right")
        if self.moving_left:
            self.player_x -= self.player_speed
            print("player had moved left")
        
        self.rect.x = self.x
```

And the Game class:

```py
def run_game(self):
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            '''self._update_bullets()'''
            self._update_screen()
            self.player.update()
            

    def _check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                self._check_keydown_events(event)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                self._check_keyup_events(event)
    
    def _check_keydown_events(self, event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.player.moving_right = True
            print("moving right")
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.player.moving_left = True
            print("moving left")
        elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
            sys.exit()    
        '''elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            self.bullets.append(Bullet(*pos))'''

    def _check_keyup_events(self, event):
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            self.moving_right = False
            print("not moving right")
        elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            self.moving_left = False
            print("not moving left")
        '''elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            self.bullets.append(Bullet(*pos))'''

def _update_screen(self):
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.player.blitme()

        pygame.display.flip()
        print("Screen had been updated")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    Game = ThatMeatball()
    Game.run_game()
```

As stated, I've added print statements but I still fail to see why the screen doesn't update, so I'm very much lost here.

Comment: `self.rect.x = self.player_x` instead of `self.rect.x = self.x`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the position of the rectangle from `self.player_x` instead `self.x`:

<s>`self.rect.x = self.x`</s>

```py
self.rect.x = self.player_x
```